# Creating and clearing widgets in KivyMD result in memory(RAM) increases

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

## Summary

Hello everyone! I am working on a large KivyMD project that involves many different screens for displaying various information. I was initially loading all of these screens in as a single KV file and the load times got to the point where the OS would think the program crashed.

I decided to create each new "Screen" dynamically by manually adding and deleting the widgets using python. The load times improved, but I noticed that each time a new set of widgets were added and deleted, the system memory(RAM) was increased. I then made the test program below to demonstrate this behavior and I cannot figure out what is causing it. **My goal is to create and delete widgets at will without an increase in RAM.**

## Information

1. KivyMD: 1.0.2
2. Kivy: 2.1.0
3. Python: 3.10.4
4. Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10

## What I tried

I have been racking by brain on this for weeks now and I can't figure it out. I have tried using the gc.collect() to manually clear memory that is no longer referenced, tried the "del" function in python to remove the widgets after creating them and other things.

My current theory is that something is holding a reference to these widgets and the "clear_widgets()" or "remove_widget()" functions are not removing the references to these items, but only clearing them off the screen. I have tried to track down the references to the widgets using heapy/guppy, but I am not skilled enough to know how to understand the output. It might also be something really simple I overlooked.

## Code example

Run the following code and you will see the system RAM increase in size until the process is killed.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

counter = 0

class MainApp(MDApp):
        
    def build(self):
        #Add MDFloatLayout as root widget
        layout = MDFloatLayout()
        #Schedule add_items() function to be called every second 
        self.clock_obj = Clock.schedule_interval(self.add_items, 1)
        return layout
            
    def add_items(self, dt):
        #Increment global counter
        global counter
        counter += 1
        #Clear all widgets
        self.root.clear_widgets()
        label = MDLabel(text="Count " + str(counter), 
                        pos_hint={"x": 0.5, "top": 0.5}, size_hint=(.1, .1))
        button= MDRectangleFlatButton(text="Count " + str(counter),
                                      pos_hint={"x": 0.5, "top": 0.6}, 
                                      size_hint=(.1, .1))
        field = MDTextField(hint_text="Count " + str(counter), mode="fill", 
                            pos_hint={"x": 0.5, "top": 0.7},
                            size_hint=(.1, .1))
        #Add all widgets to parent layout
        self.root.add_widget(label)
        self.root.add_widget(button)
        self.root.add_widget(field)
        return
```

Please let me know if any additional information is required to troubleshoot this issue. Thank you in advance.

## Update 9/3/22

For anyone interested, a bug ticket has been filed on the KivyMD Github. Troubleshooting is ongoing

Comment: Please, provide the errors screens so others can better understand the problem.

Comment: @SamirHinojosa Thank you for your comment. The above Kivy program runs without any errors. The problem is that the RAM usage for the python task increases every time the "add_items()" function is called. This can be viewed by opening Task Manager on Windows or System Monitor on Ubuntu(Linux). I can post some screenshots of the System Monitor over the course of a few minutes if that would be helpful?

Comment: When I run your code I see memory usage increase for a while, then decrease when garbage collection occurs. I am running python v3.10.4, kivy v2.1.0, and kivymd 1.0.0.dev0 under Ubuntu 20.04. What are you running?

Comment: Oops, I see that you had already posted the info I requested. If you are not getting any error messages, how do you know it's a memory problem? Memory usage will normally increase to a point. Is it causing system hang or app crash?

Comment: @JohnAnderson. Thank you checking it out. I just tried the program again on another machine running Windows 10, Python 3.8.8, Kivy 2.0.0 and KivyMD 1.0.2. I ran the program for around 10 minutes and the RAM usage increased to about 500MB and still climbing before I killed the task. How long did you wait on your setup before you saw the garbage collection?

Comment: I saw garbage collection very quickly. You can use [gc](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/gc.html) to watch the garbage collection.

Comment: I do see memory use constantly increase. I modified your code run the interval at 0.1 seconds and to stop at count == 500 and see a usage of about 540 MB. Have you tried letting your process run until it crashes your system due to memory use?

Comment: @JohnAnderson. I have not let it run to the point were the program/OS will crash, but I have run it to the point were the interface will start to lag and become slower. I started the program up again and I will let it run until something fails. I will report back my findings. Thank you again for the assistance.

Comment: So I let the program run for around 3 hours. The RAM usage would keep climbing until it started to cache it to disk. The program never crashed completely, but was very laggy and certain widgets were not displaying. The machine in question has 8GB of RAM and the python process used 5.6GB at it's peak. I noticed that the paging file allocation was almost to it's limit. Windows 10 is pretty hard to crash compared to older versions of Windows

Comment: Since your issue seems to be based on dynamically building `Screens`, perhaps you should just build each `Screen` as it is needed, but without removing any `Screens`. So that each `Screen` gets built just once and kept in `ScreenManager`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson That is sort of what my actual program does, but I still need to add/delete dynamic content from the screens. I made another test program using a `Screen` that adds and deletes elements. It also suffers from the above mentioned memory issues. Stack Overflow is telling me to avoid "extended" discussions in the comments, so I will just reiterate my immediate goal. **Can I add and delete dynamic widgets/layouts from KivyMD without suffering an increasing RAM penalty every time?** Thank you again for your time

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any way to avoid that behavior short of restarting your app in another process.

Comment: @JohnAnderson That is not the answer I was expecting, but it does make me feel a little better that it wasn't something super obvious I overlooked. I will do some more testing and I might submit a bug ticket on the Kivy/KivyMD project Github. I find it hard to believe the developers of Kivy designed a framework that allows you to build complex UI's and not have a mechanism to cleanly remove widget elements from memory. That seems like a major limitation. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

The issue I had with memory leaks in Windows and Linux has been resolved. It seems to have been a bug in KivyMD that was patched recently. The bug had to do with certain properties not being "unbound" when the widgets were cleared.

### Resolution

Install the current Dev(Master) branch with,

```
pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

The current stable release(1.0.2) does **NOT** have this fix yet